# Side-effects of display_reset() and texture_set_interpolation()

Tags: game-maker-studio-1.4, game-maker-language

It seems like display_reset() also resets the texture interpolation setting.

Can someone explain to me what happens internally when you mix texture_set_interpolation and display_reset? The docs tell me nothing, yet when i have interpolation enabled and switch on 8x AA, my sprite lines get pixely again. When i immediately call texture_set_interpolation after the display_reset() it still doesn't work - i'll have to wait a few steps before i can enable it and it removes the pixely lines.

This isn't optimal for my game initialisation code - it loads the users' preferences, and calls display_reset() and calls texture_set_interpolation() afterwards. It ends up with textures still being pixely.

Note: I feel like the anti-alias changes do nothing. I have a smoke-line-texture that i transform with a shader to make it feel real, (this warps the smoke), but the lines are all very pixelly - it looks the same in 0 antialias as it does on 8x antialias. It only looks smooth when i enable texture interpolation.